# Cannot link against boost filesystem in qt

Tags: c++, qt, boost

in qt's pro file I've typed:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "D:\\Libraries\\boost_1_47_0\\boost_1_47_0"
LIBS += -L"D:\\Libraries\\boost_1_47_0\\boost_1_47_0\\stage\\lib" -llibboost_filesystem-mgw46-d-1_47.a
```

but I'm getting an error:
**:-1: error: cannot find -llibboost_filesystem-mgw46-d-1_47.a**
the file is definitely there. Anybody knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put the prefix or extension of the library name in the `-l` parameter.

Use something like:

```
-lboost_filesystem-mgw46-d-1_47
```

Comment: #Mat I'm getting now D:\..\..\..\..\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\system\error_code.hpp:214: error: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'

Comment: You probably need to link against `boost_system` too then?*