# Boost::Regex in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, boost, qt4, qt-creator, boost-regex

I'm a bit new to libraries and using anything other than Visual Studios to write C++. I was hoping to get help with installing Boost 1_49_0 for use with Qt Creator 4.8.1 on my Windows 7 computer.

Edit: I need specific instructions on how libraries are added within Qt Creator. When I try to add library and go to eternal library, why does is only show the libraries with a .lib extension and not the ones with a .a extension?

Answer (score 0):

Can't see any problems. Just download boost development libraries, add the include paths to your Qt project, tell linker what libraries to use, and you're done.

Have a look at [Adding Libraries to Projects](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.3/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html) from Qt documentation.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that I'm apparently too dense to even understand that tutorial. When I try to include boost I can only include one .lib file and I need to include a folder of .lib files and also have a bunch of other files also. 

I added a screenshot to try and make my point more clear (since I'm not really sure what other information I can provide you).

[Picture](http://i.imgur.com/6RpxY.png)

Comment: First of all, you don't need add a folder of all the lib files. If you use boost regex, add only boost regex. Secondly, `.lib` files are for MS Visual Studio, while you need to download boost for MinGW, since Qt uses MinGW compiler.

Comment: Would I follow a guide like [this?](http://ascend4.org/Binary_installer_for_Boost_on_MinGW)

Comment: Sure, you could just use that installer to install boost built for MinGW, it should work. Ignore second section about building boost by yourself.

Comment: So I used that to install boost for MinGW and now I try to link to an external library. I put the include file as "C:\Program Files (x86)\Boost-1.41.0\include" and the lib file I could only guess would be "C:\Program Files (x86)\Boost-1.41.0\lib\libboost_regex-mgw34-mt.lib" But you said that .lib files are only for MSVS.

Comment: This is what my .pro file added
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../Program Files (x86)/Boost-1.41.0/lib/ -llibboost_regex-mgw34-mt
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../Program Files (x86)/Boost-1.41.0/lib/ -llibboost_regex-mgw34-mtd

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../Program Files (x86)/Boost-1.41.0/include/boost-1_41/boost
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../Program Files (x86)/Boost-1.41.0/include/boost-1_41/boost

It's giving me an error when I try to #include </boost/regex.hpp>

Comment: MinGW libraries has `.a` extension, not lib. Secondly, when you specify libraries to GCC based linkers, you should drop *lib* prefix. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278348/cannot-link-against-boost-filesystem-in-qt

Comment: So I should not be trying to right click and adding library? When I do it only finds the .lib files and not my .a files. I tried this like what you  linked  
 
    `INCLUDEPATH += C:/boost_1_49_0
LIBS += -LC:/boost_1_49_0/stage/lib -llibboost_regex-mgw46-mt-1_49`
And it still does not find /boost/regex.hpp –